# Emails go to spam from server A, but form server B not (same configuration)

Tags: email-server, ovh

I have puzzle with my So You Start servers from OVH - from server A my mails go to google spam folder, but from server B it is ok.
I'm not sure that it is problem with SOS servers or some IP addresses.
I checked every IP address with blacklist - not listed.

Description of problem.
Server A has 3 IP (A.1 , A.2, A.3) which are connect with on VM.
Server B has 3 IP (B.1 , B.2, B.3) which are connect with on VM.
For each IP (VM) I added one domain.

When I sent e-mail from A.1, email went to spam.
When I sent e-mail from A.2, email went to spam.
When I sent e-mail from A.3, email went to spam.

BUT!

When I move VM from server A to server B and attach IP B.1 everything is ok.
Domain is the same.
Just move VM from server A to B and change IP address.
As I said earlier I've tested with all IP on server A - every mail went to spam.
From server B - every mail went to received folder.

Mail IP from server A and B are not black listed.
Google said that mail server settings are ok (SPF, DKIM, DMARC).

Could be some issue with gateway of server A?
How can I track this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's spam classification criteria are notoriously opaque. They may be taking into account the server IP, even if the IP is not in public blacklists (just based on abuse with their own users). Or they could be doing all sorts of other things.

As Google is unwilling to cooperate with other providers about this, I'm not sure there is a solution other than testing your setup with other providers, or with your own mail servers with open-source spam filtering solutions (SpamAssassin, rspamd). If your mail isn't flagged as spam in that case, then I'm afraid there's no choice but accept that Google will sometimes flag your mail as spam for no discernible reason... and hope that GMail users are aware of the implications of their choice.

Comment: Ok. It's sad information :( 
Thank you for the answer.